# Error is showing while setup distributed performance testing

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, distributed-computing, jmeter-plugins

I want to perform distributed performance testing in JMeter, I am unable to create the rmi_keystore.jks as error is showing in command prompt, I have tried in many different way but unable to create, If I run the Jmeter and go to run option and select the IP then Error is showing as I was unable to create the keystore file.
I am stuck at the beginning. 
Please refer screenshot of Error for reference. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Try run the cmd as administrator

Comment: Yea I have already tried but still getting the same error.

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? If answer is ok you should accept it and upvote.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you install a JDK 8 and that you have in Windows path :

> <full path to jdk_home>/bin

Or edit the create-rmi-keystore.bat and add the full path before keytool:

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\bin\keytool"

Run the command create-rmi-keystore.bat once and then copy the file on all machines.

Comment: This is the path of JDK C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\bin and JRE C:\Program Files\Java\jre-10.0.2\bin

Comment: Even When I am running the jmeter-server.bat file following error is showing in command prompt.Server failed to start: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Listen failed on port: 0; nested exception is:
        java.io.FileNotFoundException: rmi_keystore.jks (The system cannot find the file specified)
An error occurred: Listen failed on port: 0; nested exception is:
        java.io.FileNotFoundException: rmi_keystore.jks (The system cannot find the file specified)
errorlevel=1

Comment: After Adding full path of keytool before it, following error is showing. 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: this is due to space, add "

Comment: Thank you so much, Its work for me and solved my all problems.

Comment: In this case you should accept answer by clicking on the check at left of answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is due to missing [`keytool.exe`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html) utility in your operating system path, most probably your Java installation is partially broken.

The question is: do you really need to create this `rmi_keystore.jks` file? If you're afraid that your very important test metrics like response time or latency can be stolen by a malefactor - make sure to add the "bin" folder of your [JRE](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html) or [JDK](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) to [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) like:

```
set PATH=c:\java\bin;%PATH% 
jmeter.bat
```

---

If your environment is safe enough you can turn off encryption of the traffic between JMeter master and slaves by adding the next line to *user.properties* file (it has to be done on all nodes)

```
server.rmi.ssl.disable=true
```

or alternatively pass the above property via -J command-line argument like:

```
jmeter.bat -Jserver.rmi.ssl.disable=true
```

As a bonus you will get slightly increased maximum number of virtual users/throughput as encryption/decryption of data is a quite CPU-intensive process

The answer is inspired in part by [JMeter Distributed Testing with Docker](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-distributed-testing-with-docker) article

Answer (score 0):

After adding the path of keytool it works
I have added the following path in create-rmi-keystore.bat file
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\bin\keytool" -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias rmi -keystore rmi_keystore.jks -storepass changeit -validity 7 -keysize 2048 %*